When will the lazy execution of a ParDo in Apache Beam Python be executed?
I'm wondering when would a generator value be evaluated when running in a beam pipeline and how the distributed computing would work in this case as the documentation for ParDos does not really mention this.
The goal would be that the ParDo lazy loads all the filenames in my bucket to then load and process them on the highest number of workers in do_something_with_df.
Considering the following code snippet:
import apache_beam as beam

class AcquireCsvs(beam.DoFn):

  def process(self, element: None) -> Iterable[pd.Dataframe]:
     files = beam.io.GcsIO().list_files("some location")
     for file in files:
         yield self._load_file(file)

  def _load_file(self, filename) -> pd.Dataframe:
     with beam.io.GcsIO().open(filename) as file:
        return pd.read_csv(file)

 with beam.Pipeline() as p:
     (
        p 
        | beam.Create([None])
        | beam.ParDo(AcquireCsvs())
        | beam.Map(do_something_with_df)
     )
     

when would the _load_file method be executed for each file? Would it be in the do_something_with_df function as I would like it to ? Or would they all get evaluated already as part of the ParDo and therefore blocking all my pipeline on the same initial worker ?
Thanks for any pointers you can provide!
